# Proxy doesn't work with fetch() in React.js

Tags: reactjs, proxy, port, fetch-api

I've made a simple project in React; the client is running at port 3000, server at 3001.

If I launch `localhost:3001/api/visitator/cars` it works correctly, but when I make the GET Request on Client I have this error, on console `http://localhost:3000/api/visitator/cars 404 (Not found)`.

I don't know why, but the request is done on port 3000 and not 3001, even if on package.json is present
`"proxy": "http://localhost:3001".`

This is the code in `client/api`:

```
async function askForCars(){

let url = '/api/visitator/cars'
const response = await fetch(url);
const carJson = await response.json();
if(response.ok){
    console.log(carJson)
    return carJson;
} else {
    let err = {status: response.status, errObj:carJson};
    throw err;  // An object with the error coming from the server
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you change url variable as  `let url = 'http://localhost:3001/api/visitator/cars'` and log `carJson` variable to see what you get ?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve this:

1. You have give the full path rather than relative path as your server lies on a different domain as ports are different. So your url variable value should be the  domain name + uri + i.e. `http://localhost:3001/api/visitator/cars`.
2. The second way to solve this would be you need to add redirect rules on the server where you are hosting the app so that your every request having `http://localhost:3000/api` uri should be redirected to `http://localhost:3001/api`.

I think the quick solution would be the first one for now incase you don't have requirement to redirect api calls to actual server. Hope it helps.